# Formato especial de Fecha SQLServer 2012

Tags: sql-server

Estoy armando una consulta en SQLServer 2012 donde la fecha la quiero en un formato así por ejemplo: 1 de Diciembre del 2019

Alguien ha hecho algo similar?

Gracias

Comment: ¿Qué has escrito hasta ahora y qué resultados arroja?

Comment: Hola, llevas algo de tiempo en el sitio, recuerda realizar las preguntas en base a [ask], saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba esto

```
--cambia el getdate() con el nombre del campo
SET LANGUAGE spanish;
select CONCAT(day(getdate()), ' de ', datename(mm,GETDATE()) ,' del ', year(getdate()))
```

Comment: Es importante leer [¿Cómo escribo una buena respuesta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) para formular una respuesta de calidad y que esta sea bien recibida. Evita responder a preguntas de baja calidad que no muestran lo que han intentado. Ademas de esto tu respuesta se basa solamente en código.

Answer (score 2):

Te dejo varias opciones. Ten en cuenta que el formato se deja para la capa final de presentación para poder mantener todas las propiedades del tipo original. También es importante recalcar que la función FORMAT es altamente costosa y puede ser hasta 40 veces más lenta que otras soluciones.

```
SET LANGUAGE spanish;

SELECT fecha,
    STUFF( CONVERT( varchar(50), fecha, 103), 3, 4, CONCAT( ' de ', DATENAME( MM, fecha), ' del ')),
    FORMAT( fecha, 'D', 'es-es'),
    FORMAT( fecha, 'd \de MMMM \del yyyy')
FROM (VALUES(GETDATE()))x(Fecha)
```